# remove null in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

[ASK]

how to remove null in mysql?

```
CREATE VIEW konsumenlist AS select 
(select nama_konsumen  where jenis_kelamin_konsumen="laki-laki" ) as Laki_laki,
(select nama_konsumen  where jenis_kelamin_konsumen="perempuan" ) as Perempuan  
from konsumen;
select * from konsumenlist;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's very easy if I understood you rightly. You need to use `IFNULL` or `COALESCE`

```
CREATE VIEW konsumenlist AS select 
IFNULL((select nama_konsumen  where jenis_kelamin_konsumen="laki-laki" ),'---') as Laki_laki,
COALESCE((select nama_konsumen  where jenis_kelamin_konsumen="perempuan" ),'---') as Perempuan  
from konsumen;
```